# Why doesnt move capture in C++14 use [&&move_me_into_lambda] syntax?

Tags: lambda, c++14

I like new C++14 addition of giving lambdas ability to capture move only arguments, but I am not a fan of the syntax:
[Move capture in lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640393/move-capture-in-lambda)

What is a a reason that simpler

```
auto f = [&&x]{return x->twenty_perc_cooler();};
```

was not used?

Comment: I think that would be surprising and contradict the design of rvalue references. The point of an rvalue reference is to document that the value is not aliased, and transfer of the the unique reference holder is explicit via `std::move`. Your proposal would make the no-aliasing guarantee hard to follow and brittle.

Comment: Moreover, what's the point? What would the difference be between `[&x](){}` and `[&&x](){}`? In both cases `x` must refer to an existing, named value.

Comment: after lambda in first case if x is vector x is not empty, in second it is.

Comment: Why? You're just binding a reference, not mutating any state?

Comment: to make it clear I want this: std::vector<int> vi{1,2,3,47};  auto f = [&&vi](){};  assert(0==v.size()); same for unique_ptr, other user defined types...

Comment: That seems like a terrible idea. It would create a completely unique and idiosyncratic meaning of `&&`.

Comment: sure, like &x everywher else except in [] means take address of, not a reference

Comment: Taking the address of something also doesn't mutate it, but in any case the capture syntax is of course reminiscent of the declaration syntax `[T] & x`, `[T] && x`, `[T] x`.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Are you sure that's guaranteed in other cases? I don't recall any such guarantee, and entertain some doubt that it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was actually addressed in [N3610](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3610.html), a proposal regarding capture-by-move:

> Why not capture with &&?
>
> It's often asked why we wouldn't just support something like
>
> [&&x] { ... }
>
> The issue here is that we're not capturing by an rvalue reference, we
>   are attempting to move. If we would capture by rvalue reference, the
>   move would occur too late, since it's intended to happen at capture
>   time, not at call time. And as long as we're capturing something that
>   has a name, we shouldn't do a hidden move from it.

Comment: I disagree with the decision, but nice find, accepting