# How to move future into lambda-expression

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, move, future

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and i want achieve this line of code

```
 f = p.get_future();
 auto task =[f = std::move(f)](){
   //use f
 };
```

I'm aware of the solution
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640393/move-capture-in-lambda), but unfortunately this doesn't compile under VS2013 (`error C2558 no copy-constructor available`).

Comment: Get a shared_future and capture by value ?

Comment: Captures with initializers are a C++14 feature, not C++11.

Comment: Wait, are you talking about a lambda-expression or a `std::function`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `shared_future`.  That is easiest.

However, that doesn't help you move.  If you really need to move, we can do it with the help of a `move_helper` function and class:

```
template<class T, class F=void>
struct move_helper_t {
  T t;
  F f;
  template<class...Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...args)
  ->typename std::result_of< F&(T&, Args...) >::type
  {
    return f(t, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  // force right-associativity of `->*`, and
  // invert the stack to get the arguments in the "right" order:
  template<class F1,
    class R0=move_helper_t< T, typename std::decay<F1>::type >
  >
  auto operator->*(F1&& f1)
  -> decltype(
    std::declval<F>()->*
    std::declval<R0>()
  )
  {
    return
      std::move(f)->*
      R0{ std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<F1>(f1) };
  }
};
template<class T>
struct move_helper_t<T,void> {
  T t;
  template<class F>
  auto operator->*(F&& f)
  -> move_helper_t<T, typename std::decay<F>::type>
  {
    return {std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<F>(f)};
  }
};

template<class T>
move_helper_t<std::decay_t<T>>
move_helper( T&& t ) {
  return {std::forward<T>(t)};
}
```

In MSVC 2013 you *may* have to declare a constructor in `move_helper_t`.  I do not recall how well written their `return {}` code was.

```
f = p.get_future();
task =
  move_helper(std::move(f)) ->*
  [](std::future<int>& f){
    //use f
  };
```

`->*` binds the `move_helper` to the lambda.  It then returns a callable object which will be passed the `std::future<int>&` as the first argument when invoked.

Because of how it is written, you can even chain it:

```
auto f = p.get_future();
auto f2 = p2.get_future();
task =
  move_helper(std::move(f)) ->*
  move_helper(std::move(f2)) ->*
  [](std::future<int>& f, std::future<char>& f2){
    //use f
  };
```

to move more than one argument into the lambda.

In both cases, `task` can be invoked by `task()` -- the `->*` operation binds the lambda up and passes the futures when invoked.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8dbc52ac651cca7).

Note that this solves the problem of moving the future into the lambda.  If you want to store the lambda in a `std::function`, this *will not help you*, as functions must be copyable.

```
template<class F>
struct shared_function {
  std::shared_ptr<F> pf;
  template<class ...Args>
  typename std::result_of<F&(Args...)>::type
  operator()(Args&&...args) const {
   return (*pf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
template<class F,
  class dF=typename std::decay<F>::type
>
shared_function< dF >
make_shared_function( F&& f ) {
  return {std::make_shared<dF>(std::forward<F>(f))};
}
```

this takes a movable lambda and wraps it in a shared pointer and exposes `operator()` for you.  But first taking a `future` moving it into a lambda via the above technique, and then wrapping that lambda in a shared function to pass it to a `std::function` is ridiculous: just use a `shared_future` in the first place.

As an aside, in theory, a `packaged_task` only requires move, but I am uncertain if MSVC2013 supports that requirement.

Comment: Not your fault, but this is absolutely disgusting.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I dunno, I think my post history has strong evidence that the disguistingness of my operator overloading and the like is probably my fault.  :)

Comment: Well I was trying to be nice ;) Nah seriously though it's C++. Ew.