# Cannot convert result of std::bind to std::function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm running into trouble with the following snippet:

```
std::promise<int> promise;    
auto operation = [](std::promise<int> promise) { promise.set_value(1); };
auto fn = std::bind(operation, std::move(promise));
fn();
```

Using `clang` I get the following error:

> candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Args = <>]:
>         implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::__bind_return<(lambda at promise.cpp:7:12),
>   std::__1::tuple >, std::__1::tuple<>, false>'
>           operator()(_Args&& ...__args)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want move capture. `std::bind` can't do that. [Lambda can do it starting with C++14](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640393/move-capture-in-lambda), but not in C++11.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `std::bind` can do move captures just fine. The problem is that it passes the captured thing along as an lvalue.

Comment: Your title is misleading: there is no `std::function` involved in your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Igor is quite right, but for my purposes this worked quite nicely, and is `c++11` compatible:

```
std::promise<int> promise;    
auto operation = [](std::promise<int>& promise) { promise.set_value(1); };
std::packaged_task<void ()> fn { std::bind(operation, std::move(promise)) };
fn();
```

By changing `operation` to take a reference to the `std::promise` instead of a value, and using `std::packaged_task`, which is moveable and not copyable, I can achieve the original goal of having a function I can pass around that holds a `std::promise`.

Comment: Yes sadly, there is no `std::not_packaged_task` which whould avoid the overhead of having a `std::promise` and associated shared state.

Answer (score 1):

Bound objects are passed along as lvalues, and `promise`s can't be copied.

Making your lambda take a lvalue reference will make your code compile, but might not be a great idea.

```
auto operation = [](std::promise<int>& promise) { promise.set_value(1); };
//                                   ^
```