# Thread-safety of using unique_ptr inside lambda when creating new thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lambda

I would like to know if the following code is thread-safe

```
void use_value(int i, unique_ptr<vector<int>> v);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    unique_ptr<vector<int>> ptr = make_unique<vector<int>>(10);
    // ...
    // Here, the vector pointed to by ptr will be filled with specific values for each thread.
    // ....
    thread(
        [i, &ptr](){
            use_value(i, move(ptr));
        }
    );
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps this is not your real code, but this example program will terminate after the first iteration of the loop, as the `std::thread` is [destroyed while still in a joinable state](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread).

Comment: @Oktalist you are right, it is not the real code; but I got interested in the point. You mean the newly created thread, because of RAII?

Comment: `std::thread` is not a thread, it manages a thread. `thread([i, &ptr](){use_value(i, move(ptr));});` constructs a temporary `std::thread` which is immediately destroyed after the last `;`. Destroying an initialized `std::thread` without first calling `join()` or `detach()` will result in premature program termination. You need to move (or emplace construct) the `std::thread` somewhere else so it's not immediately destroyed, which is what your real code presumably already does.

Comment: @Oktalist Yes, that's correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's undefined behavior. You don't know when the lambda body will be called. So that `ptr` you capture by reference can very well be out of scope by then, the resource destructed, and you are left with a dangling reference.

You should ["move-capture"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640393/move-capture-in-lambda) the `ptr` (or better yet, just the `vector`) into the lambda, if you have access to c++14.

If you move (or copy) the vector, your code *will be* thread safe.

Comment: Just a nit: this is about lifetime, not scope.

Comment: @AhmadSiavashi, only the reference is captured on lambda creation. The body may be called at any time when `std::thread` is involved.

Comment: @hvd, You are very much correct. But I had to address this sort of glaring mistake first.

Comment: @StoryTeller yes, but unfortunately I'm using MSVC++ 2013. You now about it and the messy workarounds that have been suggested.

Comment: @StoryTeller If I copy the vector using unique_ptr will be meaningless. Am I right?

Comment: @AhmadSiavashi, `std::unique_ptr` isn't copyable, only moveable. If you don't mind a little overhead (and "little" depends on the size of your vector), you can substitute `std::shared_ptr` for it, and copy that.

Comment: @StoryTeller You are right, but the size of the vector varies greatly. I'm still thinking of workarounds. The problem is with Microsoft's implementation of standard libraries. One cannot use 'std::move' along 'std::async' or 'thread'

Comment: @AhmadSiavashi I suggest you write correct code first, and optimize second. The overhead may end up being negligable.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, that's probably the main option beside upgrading MSVC and migrating to c++14. Thank you.

Comment: It seems rather than a vector being passed in standard 'scatter/gather' type approach is the solution.  Is there a reason you are storing the parameters in a vector at all?

Comment: @WilliamJones, you should comment that on the original post (or tag the persion who opened the question by prepending `@` to their name.) Otherwise only I get notified about it, since this is my answer.