# What is the lifetime of objects captured by reference in an asynchronous function in C++?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, lambda

Is the following code safe?

```
void foo() {
  Object bar;
  callback_in_5_sec([&]() {
    print(bar);
  });
} // bar goes out of scope but is it being retained because it is captured?
```

Comment: No, `bar` is destroyed once it gets out of scope of `foo`.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Move capture in lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640393/move-capture-in-lambda).