# Correct way to pass r-value reference unique pointer into lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, unique-ptr

I'm new to C++ and am working on an existing codebase, and am trying to figure out how to pass an r-value ref unique pointer into a lambda and transfer ownership properly.

Currently, we have:

```
void MyClass::onResponse(uniq_ptr<Foo>&& response) {
    parent_.doSomething(std::move(response));
}
```

I need to modify this to do some stuff (fire a timer, basically) on the main thread using a function `postToMainThread` which takes a lambda, and then call `doSomething` as before. Posting to main thread with a dummy response works fine, but when I try to pass/move the lambda through, I get a segfault as something on the other side tries to take ownership of the response:

```
void MyClass::onResponse(uniq_ptr<Foo>&& response) {
    postToMainThread([this, &response]() {
        // Do some stuff that must be on main thread
        parent_.doSomething(std::response);
    }
}
```

I've seen a number of examples that use `postToMainThread([this, response = std::move(response)]() {...` but that does not compile due to a copy constructor on unique pointer error. I gather I need to transfer ownership of the response, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640393/move-capture-in-lambda

Comment: `[this, response = std::move(response)]` should be what you want.  Most likely, the problem is with `postToMainThread`

Comment: Yeah, `std::move(response)` should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out. I added a `response_` property to MyClass, and moved it in `MyClass::onResponse()`. That in turn fired the post and timer, which called a new `MyClass::XXX()`. This in turn performed `parent_.doSomething(std::move(response_))` with the stored response. Whew!