# lambda move capture for std::thread

Tags: c++, c++17

I am implementing a timer library inspired by [Simple Timer](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/28/timer-cpp/)

```
#ifndef CMS_TIMER
#define CMS_TIMER

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

class Timer {
    std::atomic_bool clear = false;

public:
    template<class Function, class... Args, class Rep, class Period>
    [[maybe_unused]] void setInterval(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& sleep_duration, Function&& f, Args&&... args);
    void stop();
};

template<class Function, class... Args, class Rep, class Period>
void Timer::setInterval(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& sleep_duration, Function&& f, Args&&... args) {
    this->clear = false;
    std::thread t([std::move(args)]() {
        while(true) {
            if (this->clear) return;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(sleep_duration);
            if(this->clear) return;
            f(args);
        }
    });
    t.detach();
}

void Timer::stop() {
    this->clear = true;
}
#endif
```

But I am not sure what to use instead of `[std::move(args)]` I need to function and arguments them by move semantics,

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640393/move-capture-in-lambda) didn't help me

Comment: Why do you think you need something different? It's not really clear what the problem is here.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings because the placement of the `...` expansion is weird.

Comment: @HTNW "Weird" how? Can we have some specifics please?

Comment: Why can't you just put an = in there and pass by value?

Comment: by using [=] I am getting Initializers contain unexpanded parameter pack `args`

Comment: Note: If you use `sleep_for` your timing won't be very accurate. Use `sleep_until` instead and use a timepoint that ju just add a fixed duration to instead.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings In C++20, the `...` would go like `[...args = std::move(args)]() { /* ... */ f(args...); }` which is entirely non-obvious and is not covered in the linked question. Apparently that syntax doesn't exist in C++17, which is why the `std::tuple` mess is needed. @JosephLarson that would copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class Function, class... Args, class Rep, class Period>
void Timer::setInterval(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& sleep_duration, Function&& f, Args&&... args) {
    this->clear = false;
    std::thread t([this, f=std::move(f), sleep_duration, args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...))]() {
        while(true) {
            if (this->clear) return;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(sleep_duration);
            if(this->clear) return;
            std::apply(f, args);
        }
    });
    t.detach();
}
```

That should do correct capturing.  Note that as the timer goes off more than once, you don't want to further-forward data into the `f`.

But that still doesn't work because you didn't capture `this`.

Really, you should do a proper cv/mutex and not leak threads.

```
class Timer {
  std::condition_variable cv;
  mutable std::mutex m;
  bool clear = false;
  std::thread active_thread;
  void dispose_thread() {
    if (active_thread.joinable()) {
      stop();
      active_thread.join();
    }
    clear = false; // safe, because all threads are dead
  }
public:
    template<class Function, class... Args, class Rep, class Period>
    [[maybe_unused]] void setInterval(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& sleep_duration, Function&& f, Args&&... args);
    auto lock() const {
      return std::unique_lock( m );
    }
    void stop() {
      auto l = lock();
      clear = true;
      cv.notify_all();
    }
    ~Timer() { dispose_thread(); }
};

template<class Function, class... Args, class Rep, class Period>
void Timer::setInterval(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& sleep_duration, Function&& f, Args&&... args) {
    dispose_thread();
    // capture everything explicitly; when messing with threads,
    // best to understand state
    active_thread = std::thread(
      [this, f = std::move(f), sleep_duration, args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]()
      {
        while(true) {
          {
            auto l = lock();
            // return value here isn't useful, but the function is:
            (void)cv.wait_for(l, sleep_duration, [&]{ return clear; });
            if (clear)
              return;
          }
          std::apply(f, args);
        }
      }
    );
}
```

and `.stop()` and `.join()` in the destructor.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/436fq991f).

This prevents you from leaking threads and outliving your timer object and doesn't make you wait for a timer interval to set a new interval and the like.

You should also set up `sleep_until` time points, as if you want to do something every second and the `f` function takes 0.1 seconds, this will actually repeat every 1.1 seconds.

If you want to maintain multiple worker threads in one `Timer` object, I'd switch to using `std::future`s in a vector, and maybe sweeping them to clean up ones that are finished at various intervals.

The idea of waiting for existing tasks to cleanup before starting a new tasks has value to me.  If you don't like that, you could have the threads report back that they are ready to clean up, and clean them up lazily later.  But this also requires multiple `clear` variables, so the threads that are delayed don't get the wrong value when the next thread is ready to go.

Comment: Updated code is not compile able, it is saying may be there is an extra ) while creating a std::thread,

Comment: @SahibYar Yes, I missed the `)` on the `if`.

Comment: @SahibYar Also had to modify the wait syntax -- we are waiting for the timeout (A) or the signal (B), and the lambda-based `wait_for` assumes that we are waiting for the signal only.

Comment: Could you post an example usage of setInterval? I'm unable to compile it at all, latest c++. Thanks

Comment: "error C3493: 'sleep_duration' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified" and so on...

Comment: Please edit your answer so people can correctly compile it...  active_thread = std::thread(
        [this, sleep_duration, f, args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]()

Comment: @Mecanik Live example added.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thanks for editing the post, it was really annoying. Also, thanks for the example. However, it seems there is an issue with arguments. I`m unable to use arguments at all, it just won't compile. I tried to replace the tuple with C++20 style, but no success. If the arguments would work as well, this would be one hell of a solution as the timer works perfectly.

Comment: @Mecanik I just added an argument and it worked?  https://godbolt.org/z/Mfz3MGrP7 -- are you using arguments that require perfect forwarding?  That doesn't make sense because the timer fires more than once.

Comment: One last bit, VS alerts the function "    auto lock() const {
        return std::unique_lock(m);
    }" as "failed to release lock".

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Any chance you can advise on that warning about the lock? Also, is there a way to do a simple std::cout showing the "time until next run"? Thanks

Comment: @meca I do not know why your specific version of VS has a bug.  I'd advise using the [ask question] button about it.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I`m using latest VS 2019 and latest C++, unfortunately this is a problem because the timer really get's stuck randomly...