# Capture a variable in a lambda by value, const_cast it and std::move it - undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++

Suppose I am in a function such that its interface accepts a particular object only by `const` reference. In that same function I want to enqueue some task that will execute in the future and call some callback. Something like this:

```cpp
void foo(const A &a)
{
    auto callback = [a]() { processA(a); };  // passing "a" by value as "a" will go out of scope soon after returning

    enqueueTask(callback);  // execute at some point in the future

    return;
}
```

Suppose also that `processA` supports moving/forwarding and we want to take advantage of that to save ourselves an extra copy.

As it stands I believe `a` will be copied twice - once captured by value in the lambda and once when passed to `processA` since lambda captures by value are read-only, meaning `processA(std::move(a));` moves nothing.

Now, what if I were clever and I cast the `const`-ness away before passing `a` to `processA` in order to save myself a copy. Something like:

```cpp
auto callback = [a]() { processA(std::move(const_cast<A&>(a))); };
```

This should work, I tried it out:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() {}
    A(const A& other)  { std::cout << "copy" << std::endl; }
    A(A&& other) { std::cout << "move" << std::endl; }
};


void processA(A a) { std::cout << "processing a " << &a << std::endl; }  // printing its address in case it gets optimised away

int main()
{
    const A a1;
    [a1]() { processA(std::move(a1)); }();  // copied

    const A a2;
    [a2]() mutable { processA(std::move(a2)); }();  // copied

    const A a3;
    [a3]() { processA(std::move(const_cast<A&>(a3))); }();  // moved!

    return 0;
}
```

It prints

```
copy
copy
processing ...
copy
copy
processing ...
copy
move
processing ...
```

Does moving `a3` here count is undefined behaviour? I suspect it does, since it's moved into `processA` and `processA` is free to modify its parameters (modifying a const is undefined, I believe?). But here, I'm not modifying the original object, but the copy passed to the lambda. Or does that not matter since it's captured by the lambda as `const`?

EDIT: Looks like having a `mutable` qualifier **together** with a [`std::move` capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640393/move-capture-in-lambda) does the trick. [Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/zjceo7avn). The `const_cast` must be UB but I'd be curious to learn if there's nuance there in how `const` variables are captured in lambdas.

Comment: use `mutable` specifier on the lambda.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. ah, I should have marked those as `const` to illustrate better my intention

Comment: Still use `mutable` specifier on the lambda. The copy captured by it will not be `const` regardless of whether the original was `const` or not.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I'm still getting a copy with `mutable`. BUT! If specify the capture as an rvalue, that works - `const A a; [a=std::move(a)]() mutable { processA(std::move(a)); }();`

Comment: Yes, your code has UB, because the copy of `a3` inside of the lambda is `const` and must not be modified. And you already found the solution.

Comment: Sorry the last comment is wrong.